# Java -= Selenium Loop with changing variables and Excel import

Tags: java, excel, loops, selenium

So, in a nutshell, I'm trying to read values from a spreadsheet (Excel) and then assign these values to variables and later post them into a web form.  I've been successful in doing this manually, but I'm sure there is a much more efficient way to do this.  I do not know how many rows will be in the spreadsheet at first, so I need a way to have it loop through until it finds an empty row.

The web form's address are all predictable, in as much as the first number represents the row (1-PF_7, 2-PF_7, etc.

My code is below, and I apologize in advance for it's length (which is why I'm here looking for guidance :)

```
package automationframework;


import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class RV_Security {


    public static void Execute(WebDriver driver) throws Exception{
            }

//  public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        {
        String exePath = "C:\\windows\\chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

//Open website
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://atc.la.gov/rvportal.cfm");
        driver.findElement(By.id("securityportalnewnav")).click();
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("MTAzODA2")));
        driver.findElement(By.id("PF_9")).sendKeys("d*****.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("PF_10")).sendKeys("****");
        driver.findElement(By.id("PF_8")).click();
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

//New page - Select R/V Roster Submission page
        String oldTab = driver.getWindowHandle();
        driver.switchTo().frame("MTAzODA2");
        driver.findElement(By.id("PF_49")).click();
///R/V Security Submissions Form
         ArrayList<String> newTab = new ArrayList<String>
(driver.getWindowHandles());
        newTab.remove(oldTab);
            // change focus to new tab
//              driver.switchTo().window(newTab.get(1));

            Set<String> windowId = driver.getWindowHandles();    // get  
window id of current window
            Iterator<String> itererator = windowId.iterator();   

            String mainWinID = itererator.next();
            String  newAdwinID = itererator.next();

            driver.switchTo().window(newAdwinID);


driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/button")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("PF_3")).sendKeys("ABSEC LLC");
        driver.findElement(By.id("PF_4")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("PF_4")).sendKeys("8685-P");
        driver.findElement(By.id("PF_69")).sendKeys("David A. Short");
        driver.findElement(By.id("PF_71")).sendKeys("38713-T");     

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        String datetime = dateFormat.format(date);

        driver.findElement(By.id("PF_32")).sendKeys(datetime);
        driver.findElement(By.id("PF_35")).sendKeys("10");
        driver.findElement(By.id("PF_78")).sendKeys("david@absecllc.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("PF_37")).sendKeys("ONLINE");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*
[@id=\"PF_6pag_left\"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*
[@id=\"PF_6pag_left\"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*
[@id=\"PF_6pag_left\"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*
[@id=\"PF_6pag_left\"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*
[@id=\"PF_6pag_left\"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*
[@id=\"PF_6pag_left\"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*
[@id=\"PF_6pag_left\"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/span")).click();
    /** driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*
[@id=\"PF_6pag_left\"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*
[@id=\"PF_6pag_left\"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*
[@id=\"PF_6pag_left\"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*
[@id=\"PF_6pag_left\"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*
[@id=\"PF_6pag_left\"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/span")).click();
        */


        // Get Excel Data

        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(); //Create formatter

        FileInputStream fis=new 
FileInputStream("D://OneDrive//ABSEC//ATC_Reporting//expdata.xlsx");
        Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
        Sheet sh=wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Row row=sh.getRow(0);
        Cell yourCell=row.getCell(0);
        yourCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        String u1s1 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(1);
        String u1s2 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(2);
        String u1s3 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell);
        yourCell=row.getCell(3);
        String u1s4 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(4);
        String u1s5 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(5);
        String u1s6 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(6);
        String u1s7 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(7);
        String u1s8 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(8);
        String u1s9 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(9);
        String u1s10 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(10);
        String u1s11=formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell);
        yourCell=row.getCell(11);
        String u1s12 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(12);
        String u1s13 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 

        row=sh.getRow(1);
        yourCell=row.getCell(0);
        yourCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        String u2s1 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(1);
        String u2s2 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(2);
        String u2s3 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell);
        yourCell=row.getCell(3);
        String u2s4 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(4);
        String u2s5 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(5);
        String u2s6 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(6);
        String u2s7 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(7);
        String u2s8 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(8);
        String u2s9 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(9);
        String u2s10 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(10);
        String u2s11 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell);
        yourCell=row.getCell(11);
        String u2s12 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(12);
        String u2s13 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 


        row=sh.getRow(2);
        yourCell=row.getCell(0);
        yourCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        String u3s1 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(1);
        String u3s2 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(2);
        String u3s3 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell);
        yourCell=row.getCell(3);
        String u3s4 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(4);
        String u3s5 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(5);
        String u3s6 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(6);
        String u3s7 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(7);
        String u3s8 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(8);
        String u3s9 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(9);
        String u3s10 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(10);
        String u3s11 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell);
        yourCell=row.getCell(11);
        String u3s12 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(12);
        String u3s13 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 


        row=sh.getRow(3);
        yourCell=row.getCell(0);
        yourCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        String u4s1 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(1);
        String u4s2 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(2);
        String u4s3 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell);
        yourCell=row.getCell(3);
        String u4s4 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(4);
        String u4s5 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(5);
        String u4s6 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(6);
        String u4s7 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(7);
        String u4s8 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(8);
        String u4s9 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(9);
        String u4s10 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(10);
        String u4s11 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell);
        yourCell=row.getCell(11);
        String u4s12 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(12);
        String u4s13 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 


        row=sh.getRow(4);
        yourCell=row.getCell(0);
        yourCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        String u5s1 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(1);
        String u5s2 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(2);
        String u5s3 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell);
        yourCell=row.getCell(3);
        String u5s4 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(4);
        String u5s5 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(5);
        String u5s6 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(6);
        String u5s7 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(7);
        String u5s8 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(8);
        String u5s9 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(9);
        String u5s10 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(10);
        String u5s11 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell);
        yourCell=row.getCell(11);
        String u5s12 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(12);
        String u5s13 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 


        row=sh.getRow(5);
        yourCell=row.getCell(0);
        yourCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        String u6s1 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(1);
        String u6s2 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(2);
        String u6s3 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell);
        yourCell=row.getCell(3);
        String u6s4 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(4);
        String u6s5 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(5);
        String u6s6 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(6);
        String u6s7 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(7);
        String u6s8 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(8);
        String u6s9 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(9);
        String u6s10 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(10);
        String u6s11 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell);
        yourCell=row.getCell(11);
        String u6s12 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(12);
        String u6s13 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 


        row=sh.getRow(6);
        yourCell=row.getCell(0);
        yourCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        String u7s1 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(1);
        String u7s2 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(2);
        String u7s3 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell);
        yourCell=row.getCell(3);
        String u7s4 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(4);
        String u7s5 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(5);
        String u7s6 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(6);
        String u7s7 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(7);
        String u7s8 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(8);
        String u7s9 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(9);
        String u7s10 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(10);
        String u7s11 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell);
        yourCell=row.getCell(11);
        String u7s12 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(12);
        String u7s13 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 


        row=sh.getRow(7);
        yourCell=row.getCell(0);
        yourCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        String u8s1 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(1);
        String u8s2 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(2);
        String u8s3 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell);
        yourCell=row.getCell(3);
        String u8s4 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(4);
        String u8s5 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(5);
        String u8s6 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(6);
        String u8s7 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(7);
        String u8s8 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(8);
        String u8s9 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(9);
        String u8s10 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(10);
        String u8s11 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell);
        yourCell=row.getCell(11);
        String u8s12 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(12);
        String u8s13 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 

        row=sh.getRow(8);
        yourCell=row.getCell(0);
        yourCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        String u9s1 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(1);
        String u9s2 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(2);
        String u9s3 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell);
        yourCell=row.getCell(3);
        String u9s4 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(4);
        String u9s5 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(5);
        String u9s6 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(6);
        String u9s7 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(7);
        String u9s8 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(8);
        String u9s9 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(9);
        String u9s10 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(10);
        String u9s11 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell);
        yourCell=row.getCell(11);
        String u9s12 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(12);
        String u9s13 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 

        row=sh.getRow(9);
        yourCell=row.getCell(0);
        yourCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        String u10s1 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(1);
        String u10s2 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(2);
        String u10s3 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell);
        yourCell=row.getCell(3);
        String u10s4 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(4);
        String u10s5 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(5);
        String u10s6 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(6);
        String u10s7 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(7);
        String u10s8 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(8);
        String u10s9 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(9);
        String u10s10 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(10);
        String u10s11 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell);
        yourCell=row.getCell(11);
        String u10s12 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(12);
        String u10s13 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 


        row=sh.getRow(10);
        yourCell=row.getCell(0);
        yourCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        String u11s1 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(1);
        String u11s2 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(2);
        String u11s3 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell);
        yourCell=row.getCell(3);
        String u11s4 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(4);
        String u11s5 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(5);
        String u11s6 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(6);
        String u11s7 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(7);
        String u11s8 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(8);
        String u11s9 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(9);
        String u11s10 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(10);
        String u11s11 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell);
        yourCell=row.getCell(11);
        String u11s12 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(12);
        String u11s13 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 

        row=sh.getRow(11);
        yourCell=row.getCell(0);
        yourCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        String u12s1 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(1);
        String u12s2 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(2);
        String u12s3 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell);
        yourCell=row.getCell(3);
        String u12s4 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(4);
        String u12s5 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(5);
        String u12s6 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(6);
        String u12s7 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(7);
        String u12s8 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(8);
        String u12s9 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(9);
        String u12s10 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(10);
        String u12s11 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell);
        yourCell=row.getCell(11);
        String u12s12 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 
        yourCell=row.getCell(12);
        String u12s13 =formatter.formatCellValue(yourCell); 




 //Student 1
        driver.findElement(By.id("1-PF_7")).sendKeys(u1s1);
        driver.findElement(By.id("1-PF_8")).sendKeys(u1s2);
        driver.findElement(By.id("1-PF_9")).sendKeys(u1s3);
        driver.findElement(By.id("1-PF_10")).sendKeys(u1s4);
        driver.findElement(By.id("1-PF_11")).sendKeys(u1s5);
        driver.findElement(By.id("1-PF_12")).sendKeys(u1s6);
        driver.findElement(By.id("1-PF_13")).sendKeys(u1s7);
        driver.findElement(By.id("1-PF_14")).sendKeys(u1s8);
        driver.findElement(By.id("1-PF_15")).sendKeys(u1s9);
        driver.findElement(By.id("1-PF_16")).sendKeys(u1s10);
        driver.findElement(By.id("1-PF_17")).sendKeys(u1s11);
        driver.findElement(By.id("1-PF_18")).sendKeys(u1s12);
        driver.findElement(By.id("1-PF_21")).sendKeys(u1s13);

        //Student 2         
        driver.findElement(By.id("2-PF_7")).sendKeys(u2s1);
        driver.findElement(By.id("2-PF_8")).sendKeys(u2s2);
        driver.findElement(By.id("2-PF_9")).sendKeys(u2s3);
        driver.findElement(By.id("2-PF_10")).sendKeys(u2s4);
        driver.findElement(By.id("2-PF_11")).sendKeys(u2s5);
        driver.findElement(By.id("2-PF_12")).sendKeys(u2s6);
        driver.findElement(By.id("2-PF_13")).sendKeys(u2s7);
        driver.findElement(By.id("2-PF_14")).sendKeys(u2s8);
        driver.findElement(By.id("2-PF_15")).sendKeys(u2s9);
        driver.findElement(By.id("2-PF_16")).sendKeys(u2s10);
        driver.findElement(By.id("2-PF_17")).sendKeys(u2s11);
        driver.findElement(By.id("2-PF_18")).sendKeys(u2s12);
        driver.findElement(By.id("2-PF_21")).sendKeys(u2s13);

//Student 3         
        driver.findElement(By.id("3-PF_7")).sendKeys(u3s1);
        driver.findElement(By.id("3-PF_8")).sendKeys(u3s2);
        driver.findElement(By.id("3-PF_9")).sendKeys(u3s3);
        driver.findElement(By.id("3-PF_10")).sendKeys(u3s4);
        driver.findElement(By.id("3-PF_11")).sendKeys(u3s5);
        driver.findElement(By.id("3-PF_12")).sendKeys(u3s6);
        driver.findElement(By.id("3-PF_13")).sendKeys(u3s7);
        driver.findElement(By.id("3-PF_14")).sendKeys(u3s8);
        driver.findElement(By.id("3-PF_15")).sendKeys(u3s9);
        driver.findElement(By.id("3-PF_16")).sendKeys(u3s10);
        driver.findElement(By.id("3-PF_17")).sendKeys(u3s11);
        driver.findElement(By.id("3-PF_18")).sendKeys(u3s12);
        driver.findElement(By.id("3-PF_21")).sendKeys(u3s13);
//Student 4         
        driver.findElement(By.id("4-PF_7")).sendKeys(u4s1);
        driver.findElement(By.id("4-PF_8")).sendKeys(u4s2);
        driver.findElement(By.id("4-PF_9")).sendKeys(u4s3);
        driver.findElement(By.id("4-PF_10")).sendKeys(u4s4);
        driver.findElement(By.id("4-PF_11")).sendKeys(u4s5);
        driver.findElement(By.id("4-PF_12")).sendKeys(u4s6);
        driver.findElement(By.id("4-PF_13")).sendKeys(u4s7);
        driver.findElement(By.id("4-PF_14")).sendKeys(u4s8);
        driver.findElement(By.id("4-PF_15")).sendKeys(u4s9);
        driver.findElement(By.id("4-PF_16")).sendKeys(u4s10);
        driver.findElement(By.id("4-PF_17")).sendKeys(u4s11);
        driver.findElement(By.id("4-PF_18")).sendKeys(u4s12);
        driver.findElement(By.id("4-PF_21")).sendKeys(u4s13);

//Student 5     
        driver.findElement(By.id("5-PF_7")).sendKeys(u5s1);
        driver.findElement(By.id("5-PF_8")).sendKeys(u5s2);
        driver.findElement(By.id("5-PF_9")).sendKeys(u5s3);
        driver.findElement(By.id("5-PF_10")).sendKeys(u5s4);
        driver.findElement(By.id("5-PF_11")).sendKeys(u5s5);
        driver.findElement(By.id("5-PF_12")).sendKeys(u5s6);
        driver.findElement(By.id("5-PF_13")).sendKeys(u5s7);
        driver.findElement(By.id("5-PF_14")).sendKeys(u5s8);
        driver.findElement(By.id("5-PF_15")).sendKeys(u5s9);
        driver.findElement(By.id("5-PF_16")).sendKeys(u5s10);
        driver.findElement(By.id("5-PF_17")).sendKeys(u5s11);
        driver.findElement(By.id("5-PF_18")).sendKeys(u5s12);
        driver.findElement(By.id("5-PF_21")).sendKeys(u5s13);

//Student 6         
        driver.findElement(By.id("6-PF_7")).sendKeys(u6s1);
        driver.findElement(By.id("6-PF_8")).sendKeys(u6s2);
        driver.findElement(By.id("6-PF_9")).sendKeys(u6s3);
        driver.findElement(By.id("6-PF_10")).sendKeys(u6s4);
        driver.findElement(By.id("6-PF_11")).sendKeys(u6s5);
        driver.findElement(By.id("6-PF_12")).sendKeys(u6s6);
        driver.findElement(By.id("6-PF_13")).sendKeys(u6s7);
        driver.findElement(By.id("6-PF_14")).sendKeys(u6s8);
        driver.findElement(By.id("6-PF_15")).sendKeys(u6s9);
        driver.findElement(By.id("6-PF_16")).sendKeys(u6s10);
        driver.findElement(By.id("6-PF_17")).sendKeys(u6s11);
        driver.findElement(By.id("6-PF_18")).sendKeys(u6s12);
        driver.findElement(By.id("6-PF_21")).sendKeys(u6s13);

//Student 7         
        driver.findElement(By.id("7-PF_7")).sendKeys(u7s1);
        driver.findElement(By.id("7-PF_8")).sendKeys(u7s2);
        driver.findElement(By.id("7-PF_9")).sendKeys(u7s3);
        driver.findElement(By.id("7-PF_10")).sendKeys(u7s4);
        driver.findElement(By.id("7-PF_11")).sendKeys(u7s5);
        driver.findElement(By.id("7-PF_12")).sendKeys(u7s6);
        driver.findElement(By.id("7-PF_13")).sendKeys(u7s7);
        driver.findElement(By.id("7-PF_14")).sendKeys(u7s8);
        driver.findElement(By.id("7-PF_15")).sendKeys(u7s9);
        driver.findElement(By.id("7-PF_16")).sendKeys(u7s10);
        driver.findElement(By.id("7-PF_17")).sendKeys(u7s11);
        driver.findElement(By.id("7-PF_18")).sendKeys(u7s12);
        driver.findElement(By.id("7-PF_21")).sendKeys(u7s13);

//Student 8 //      
        driver.findElement(By.id("8-PF_7")).sendKeys(u8s1);
        driver.findElement(By.id("8-PF_8")).sendKeys(u8s2);
        driver.findElement(By.id("8-PF_9")).sendKeys(u8s3);
        driver.findElement(By.id("8-PF_10")).sendKeys(u8s4);
        driver.findElement(By.id("8-PF_11")).sendKeys(u8s5);
        driver.findElement(By.id("8-PF_12")).sendKeys(u8s6);
        driver.findElement(By.id("8-PF_13")).sendKeys(u8s7);
        driver.findElement(By.id("8-PF_14")).sendKeys(u8s8);
        driver.findElement(By.id("8-PF_15")).sendKeys(u8s9);
        driver.findElement(By.id("8-PF_16")).sendKeys(u8s10);
        driver.findElement(By.id("8-PF_17")).sendKeys(u8s11);
        driver.findElement(By.id("8-PF_18")).sendKeys(u8s12);
        driver.findElement(By.id("8-PF_21")).sendKeys(u8s13);   

//Student 9//       
        driver.findElement(By.id("9-PF_7")).sendKeys(u9s1);
        driver.findElement(By.id("9-PF_8")).sendKeys(u9s2);
        driver.findElement(By.id("9-PF_9")).sendKeys(u9s3);
        driver.findElement(By.id("9-PF_10")).sendKeys(u9s4);
        driver.findElement(By.id("9-PF_11")).sendKeys(u9s5);
        driver.findElement(By.id("9-PF_12")).sendKeys(u9s6);
        driver.findElement(By.id("9-PF_13")).sendKeys(u9s7);
        driver.findElement(By.id("9-PF_14")).sendKeys(u9s8);
        driver.findElement(By.id("9-PF_15")).sendKeys(u9s9);
        driver.findElement(By.id("9-PF_16")).sendKeys(u9s10);
        driver.findElement(By.id("9-PF_17")).sendKeys(u9s11);
        driver.findElement(By.id("9-PF_18")).sendKeys(u9s12);
        driver.findElement(By.id("9-PF_21")).sendKeys(u9s13);   


        //Student 10//      
        driver.findElement(By.id("10-PF_7")).sendKeys(u10s1);
        driver.findElement(By.id("10-PF_8")).sendKeys(u10s2);
        driver.findElement(By.id("10-PF_9")).sendKeys(u10s3);
        driver.findElement(By.id("10-PF_10")).sendKeys(u10s4);
        driver.findElement(By.id("10-PF_11")).sendKeys(u10s5);
        driver.findElement(By.id("10-PF_12")).sendKeys(u10s6);
        driver.findElement(By.id("10-PF_13")).sendKeys(u10s7);
        driver.findElement(By.id("10-PF_14")).sendKeys(u10s8);
        driver.findElement(By.id("10-PF_15")).sendKeys(u10s9);
        driver.findElement(By.id("10-PF_16")).sendKeys(u10s10);
        driver.findElement(By.id("10-PF_17")).sendKeys(u10s11);
        driver.findElement(By.id("10-PF_18")).sendKeys(u10s12);
        driver.findElement(By.id("10-PF_21")).sendKeys(u10s13); 


        //Student 11//      
        driver.findElement(By.id("11-PF_7")).sendKeys(u11s1);
        driver.findElement(By.id("11-PF_8")).sendKeys(u11s2);
        driver.findElement(By.id("11-PF_9")).sendKeys(u11s3);
        driver.findElement(By.id("11-PF_10")).sendKeys(u11s4);
        driver.findElement(By.id("11-PF_11")).sendKeys(u11s5);
        driver.findElement(By.id("11-PF_12")).sendKeys(u11s6);
        driver.findElement(By.id("11-PF_13")).sendKeys(u11s7);
        driver.findElement(By.id("11-PF_14")).sendKeys(u11s8);
        driver.findElement(By.id("11-PF_15")).sendKeys(u11s9);
        driver.findElement(By.id("11-PF_16")).sendKeys(u11s10);
        driver.findElement(By.id("11-PF_17")).sendKeys(u11s11);
        driver.findElement(By.id("11-PF_18")).sendKeys(u11s12);
        driver.findElement(By.id("11-PF_21")).sendKeys(u11s13); 


        //Student 12    //      
        driver.findElement(By.id("12-PF_7")).sendKeys(u12s1);
        driver.findElement(By.id("12-PF_8")).sendKeys(u12s2);
        driver.findElement(By.id("12-PF_9")).sendKeys(u12s3);
        driver.findElement(By.id("12-PF_10")).sendKeys(u12s4);
        driver.findElement(By.id("12-PF_11")).sendKeys(u12s5);
        driver.findElement(By.id("12-PF_12")).sendKeys(u12s6);
        driver.findElement(By.id("12-PF_13")).sendKeys(u12s7);
        driver.findElement(By.id("12-PF_14")).sendKeys(u12s8);
        driver.findElement(By.id("12-PF_15")).sendKeys(u12s9);
        driver.findElement(By.id("12-PF_16")).sendKeys(u12s10);
        driver.findElement(By.id("12-PF_17")).sendKeys(u12s11);
        driver.findElement(By.id("12-PF_18")).sendKeys(u12s12);
        driver.findElement(By.id("12-PF_21")).sendKeys(u12s13);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to use DataFile instead of DataFormatter:

```
DataFile df = new DataFile("D://OneDrive//ABSEC//ATC_Reporting//expdata.xlsx", "Sheet1");
```

Next define your list of variables (assume strings or integers):

```
String x = null;
String y = null;
String z = null;
```

Next Loop through your worksheet and assign the data to your variables.  The for loop assumes you have headers.

```
for (int i = 1; i < df.getRowCount(); i++) {
  //Assign your variables based on  the column headers
  x = df.getDataFromColumn("Column 1", i);
  y = df.getDataFromColumn("Column 2", i);
  z = df.getDataFromColumn("Column 3", i);
  //now you can use those variables for each row of data

}
```

Based on your code above you would have 13 variables to create, and then assign them as needed.

Also it looks like you might need to two loops, an array of Students, then loop over the excel data to input the data for that student.

```
String[] students = {"Student 1","Student 2","Student 3"}
for(String student:students){
  for (int i = 1; i < df.getRowCount(); i++) {
    //Assign your variables based on  the column headers
    x = df.getDataFromColumn("Column 1", i);
    y = df.getDataFromColumn("Column 2", i);
    z = df.getDataFromColumn("Column 3", i);
    //now you can use those variables for each row of data
  }
```

}

Comment: Brilliant!  I'm going to try this shortly.  Quick question:  If the columns don't have headers, is there another way to define the cells?

Comment: I think they are indexed, so you might be able to just use the column index.  You would want to start your loop at 0 and not 1 as well.

Comment: And I'm also interested in a way to increment the element ID's, if possible?  Am I being totally obtuse here?

Comment: @DavidS.Are the IDs dynamic or static?  If static, you could append the integer to the end of the string based on your row count...something like driver.findElement(By.id("1-PF_"+Integer.toString(i+7))).sendKeys(u1s1);

Comment: @DavidS.  My answer is not correct, it assumes that you have a Class called data file,

Comment: Yes, the ID's are static.  that's exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @DavidS. See additional answer for setting up the DataFile class.  Sorry I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

So I forgot the DataFile class, so create a new a class called DataFile and add these methods as follows

parameters:

```
private FileInputStream inFile;
private Workbook wb;
private Sheet sheet;
private Hashtable<String, Integer> headers;
```

DataFile Method:

```
public DataFile(String filePath, String sheetName){// throws 
InvalidFormatException, IOException{
    try {
        //Open the input stream to the file
        inFile = new FileInputStream(filePath);

        //Open the workbook from the InputStream and open the Worksheet
        wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inFile);
        sheet = wb.getSheet(sheetName);

        //Keep track of the column headers and their indexes
        headers = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
        Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
        for(int col=0; col < row.getLastCellNum(); col++){
            String curr = row.getCell(col).getStringCellValue();
            headers.put(curr, new Integer(col));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Get Data Column Method:

```
public String getDataFromColumn(String columnHeader, int rowNumber) {
        //Get the column number
        Integer colNum = headers.get(columnHeader);
        if (colNum == null){
            return null;
        } else if (rowNumber > sheet.getLastRowNum()){
            return null;
        }

        //Return the data from the specified cell
        Cell cell = sheet.getRow(rowNumber).getCell(colNum.intValue());

        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            return cell.getStringCellValue();
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            return Double.toString(cell.getNumericCellValue()); 
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
            return Boolean.toString(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
            return "";  
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
            FormulaEvaluator eval = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

            switch (eval.evaluateFormulaCell(cell)) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                return cell.getStringCellValue();
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                return Double.toString(cell.getNumericCellValue());
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                return Boolean.toString(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                return "";

            default:
                break;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Get Row Count (includes headers modify if no headers)

```
public int getRowCount() {
    return this.sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
```

Close File

```
public void close() throws IOException {
        this.inFile.close();
    }
```

If you are using maven, add the following dependencies to your pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>3.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you SOOO much!  I really appreciate that you came back and gave me absolutely everything I needed to make this work properly.

Comment: I apologize for not knowing the answer to this, but should this just work when I create the DataFile class and paste in the methods following the parameters?  I'm seeing  bunch of errors and not sure how to put this together.

Comment: @DavidS. Are you using maven? I edited my answer to include the correct dependencies.

Comment: I'm using eclipse oxygen.... Should I change?  I'm not tied down to anything right now

Comment: @DavidS. does your eclipse project have a pom.xml file? if so , add the dependencies there.

Comment: I converted it to a Maven project and added the dependencies.  All of the errors have gone away.  I do see warnings about some of the methods being deprecated but this is flawless now.  Thanks so much!!!!!

Comment: The only other question I would have would be how to make it read from a spreadsheet without headers, ie. column and row numbers instead...

Comment: @DavidS. in the GetRowCount method remove the +1, that should get the first row without headers.

Comment: Excellent, but then how would I refer to the data, right now it's ("Column 1", i)

Comment: @DavidS. Can update update your question with the an example of what the excel file looks like?

Comment: @DavidS. is it possible to enter column headers into your spreadsheet or a blank row?  if not you may need to tweak the getDataFromColumn method.

Comment: no, I will enter the column headers into the spreadsheet.  This works like a charm!!